# Making a skip-gram model, converting keras1.x code to keras2.x code

Tags: python-3.x, keras, nlp

I tried to follow this tutorial to make a skip-gram model:

https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-feature-engineering-part-4-deep-learning-methods-for-text-data-96c44370bbfa

The problem is that the code works with keras 1.x.

```
from keras.layers import Merge
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Reshape
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.models import Sequential

# build skip-gram architecture
word_model = Sequential()
word_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size,
                         embeddings_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                         input_length=1))
word_model.add(Reshape((embed_size, )))

context_model = Sequential()
context_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size,
                  embeddings_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                  input_length=1))
context_model.add(Reshape((embed_size,)))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([word_model, context_model], mode="dot"))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

There is no 'Merge' on keras 2.x,
so I tried to convert the code. Using dot and concatnate instead of Merge, but it didn't work. My code:

```
from keras.layers import dot
from keras.layers import concatenate
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Reshape
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.models import Sequential

# build skip-gram architecture
word_model = Sequential()
word_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size,
                         embeddings_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                         input_length=1))
word_model.add(Reshape((embed_size, )))

context_model = Sequential()
context_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size,
                  embeddings_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                  input_length=1))
context_model.add(Reshape((embed_size,)))

model = Sequential()
model.add(dot([word_model, context_model], 100))
model.add(concatenate(axis=-1))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

There is a problem at `model.add(dot([word_model, context_model], 100))` , error: `All inputs to the layer should be tensors`

If I want to continue using keras 2.x, what should I do?
thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried  `keras.layers.Multiply()` or `keras.layers.Dot(axes, normalize=False)
`